# Update when unchecked value is checked

Tags: mysql, vb.net, boolean

I have a query where the report name and report id are both displayed This only applies when the reports are pre-checked. The values are populated in a datagrid. If the report is unchecked, only the name is displayed. I tried using the UPDATE keyword but I kept running into syntax error. I know that the small change to the query is simple, but I am having a tricky time attempting to display the reportid when the report is unchecked or basically reportvisible being 0. How do I work around this to show the reportid regardless of if it is checked or not?

```
valsql1 = "SELECT c.ReportID, c.COMPANYID, rl.REPORTNAME 
           FROM CompanyReportListTable c 
             right  join  ReportList rl on c.reportid = rl.ReportID 
                                       and reportvisible = 1 
                                       and CompanyID =" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & " 
           where rl.ReportID in (
                                  Select ReportID 
                                  from ReportList 
                                  where ReportVisible = 1
                                 ) 
            order by ReportName"
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `and reportvisible = 1` from the join statement?

Comment: Reason is not to lose accuracy of appropriate reports per company. I tried removing the reportvisible from the join statement. When I ran the program, a report id was still not next to an unchecked report name. Neither did me checking the unchecked report show the report id.

Answer (score 0):

You're right joining exclusively on reportvisible = 1, and then you're specifically selecting only reportIDs with reportvisible = 1. You are twice-over filtering out rows with reportvisible = 0, so of course you aren't going to get reportids for those rows. You should add `rl.reportvisible` to the SELECT clause and remove `reportvisible = 1` from the join and where clauses.

Comment: OK here's what I got. I removed the reportvisible from the join and where clauses and added rl.reportvisible to the SELECT Clause. When I ran the program, I got more reports than needed for any selected company and the reportids still didn't show for unchecked reports.

Comment: I believe that in the query, it may only require a small, one-letter change.

Answer (score 0):

It is only a one word/two letter change. At the first SELECT statement, instead of c.ReportID, it should be rl.REPORTID. Refer back to the right join; y using a right join, it returns the selected rows from reportlist, matches it with crl table. Now we made it so reportID appears regardless if it matches or not.  Kind of like report name/title